# Unwanted files cannot be removed with SetAccessControl

Tags: c#, security, acl

We have an application on a shared server, and some unwanted files appeared on our ftp (asp file, certainly by injection or lack of security). The application is in C#.

Impossible to remove those files by FTP (unauthorized).

I've made a GetOwner request and those files seem to have as owner DOMAIN\IISUSR.

I try to change owner or to add ACL on the file, but I receive an unauthorized exception.

```
System.IO.FileInfo sFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPathFile);
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity sFS = sFile.GetAccessControl();
if (System.IO.File.Exists(sPathFile))
{
   try
   {
      IdentityReference sGet = new NTAccount(@"DOMAIN\MYUSER");
      sFS.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"DOMAIN\IISUSR", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
      sFile.SetAccessControl(sFS);
   }
}
```

I've tried with MYUSER = the ftp account (to be able to remove it by ftp.

I've tried with MYUSER = IISUSR, if the file had the ownership but without rights.

But I can get rid of the exception.

As far as its a shared server, I have IIS Admin Remote access, but so only on read level; I have access on ftp and so access through C# local execution...

Do you have an idea ?

TY !

Comment: Are you sure 'DOMAIN\MYUSER' has 'Full Control' permission on this path?

Comment: You seem to add a rule for the account that already is the owner... Note that `sGet` is never used.

Comment: IISUSR ist the ASP.NET account, your weeb application should eb able to clean up.

Comment: Thanks all.

@Alireza : MYUSER is the FTP user; I've checked other files or parent folder, this is the owner of legal files uploaded on ftp.

Comment: @Henk Hollerman : I was using sGet when I tried to add an access rule for MYUSER (not working). I tried after that to add an access rule for the  owner of the file (IISUSR), because the file cannot be deleted by my application. Is it possible that there is some deny rules for the owner ?

Comment: The problem is that your FTP account may have `modify` permissions which are enough for creating, removing and replacing the files; but to grant those permissions to someone else, you need `full control`

Comment: Yes, its the reason why I try to give full rights on a file for the ftp user; by the way, my application is run by the IISUSR no ? And cannot delete -__-"